# Can you write a single query without using any 'with' clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is the table DATA_TABLE

```
      Date        Value
01-01-2018        31.64
01-02-2018        32.09
01-03-2018        36.9
   ..              ..
```

Need output in single query as shown below

Date is a Date column, d-1 column has the value of a day before value, d for specific date value (01-02-2018) and d+2 has the value of next date in DATA_TABLE that is 36.9

O/P Needed in a single query (dates having sat and sunday should not be considered)

```
  Date             d-1           d           d+2
01-02-2018        31.64        32.09        36.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `LEAD` and `LAG` here:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    LAG(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Date) "d-1",
    Value,
    LEAD(Value) OVER (ORDER BY Date) "d+2"
FROM DATA_TABLE
```